# sub-query in a CASE expression in db2

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, case

I'm trying to use a sub-query in a CASE expression but am failing. I'm using DB2, I work with a bank database and trying to select all clients (clients type 5) who have accounts or does not have an account.
If they do have an active account, then I would like to display that account as a 1 column instead of 3. 
I do realize I can do such a thing using OUTER JOIN but I rather master the CASE expression as best as I can.
I appreciate any assistance ;)

```
select  internal_id, bank_num, identity_number, type_of_identity,
    country_id, activity_status
CASE
    WHEN activity_status = 0 THEN 'INACTIVE'
    WHEN activity_status = 1 THEN (
select  bank_num ||'-'|| branch_num||'-'|| account_num as acc 
from    atlmn.atala021 LA02 
where   LA02.internal_id = L100.internal_id)
    ELSE 'null'
    END activity
from    atlmn.atal1001 L100 
where   bank_num = 10
and type_of_client = 5
```

I'm receiving the following error instead:

> ERROR [21000] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0811N The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is mre than one row. SQLSTATE=21000

Comment: "I can do such a thing using OUTER JOIN but I rather master the CASE expression as best as I can"... That is a poor performance choice. In a 1 million records select you would execute 1000001 table accesses (1 for the main query and 1 million extra for each row). Mastering joins is tricky but will help you a lot troubleshooting

Comment: I agree @bradbury9, but performance wasn't the issue. I want to learn the syntax properly, when it finally comes to performance I would definitely use the most efficient way.

Comment: The issue isn't your syntax, it's the logic of the subquery which is returning more than one record.

Comment: Then you could do a `TOP 1` or `group by` in the subselect to ensure there is only one row returned, but without sample data is hard to know best approach at rewriting it.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential problems with your code.  First, there is a missing comma after `activity_status` in the select list.  Second, if that subquery in the `CASE` expression could return more than one record, then it will certainly cause an error.  Here is the corrected version:

```
SELECT
    internal_id,
    bank_num,
    identity_number,
    type_of_identity,
    country_id,
    activity_status,    -- added a comma here
    CASE
        WHEN activity_status = 0 THEN 'INACTIVE'
        WHEN activity_status = 1 THEN
        (
            SELECT bank_num ||'-'|| branch_num||'-'|| account_num  -- no alias needed
            FROM atlmn.atala021 LA02 
            WHERE LA02.internal_id = L100.internal_id
        )
        ELSE 'null'
    END activity
FROM atlmn.atal1001 L100 
WHERE
    bank_num = 10 AND type_of_client = 5
```

Again the above assumes that your subquery will always return a single record.  If not, then you'll have to fix your logic.  Without knowing your data it would be hard to make a suggestion.

Comment: The comma was missing since I had to adjust the entire query to fit StackOverflow, since the column names are in our language it would have been harder for you to understand the internal logic, hence why I had to simpllify it.
And while doing so I missed a comma.
Anyway, I figured out what was the problem. Every client can have more than 1 account, and as a result the subquery would provide multiple records instead of a single.
Thanks for the assistance ;)

Comment: Then we need to find a fix for the subquery.  Writing it as a join would probably get around the error, but you still might have unwanted duplicates in your result set.